# how to fix terraform remote state and local state mismatch

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

my teammate is working with terraform v0.12.28,i started working with him but i was using v0.13.x and made some changes, we use state file which is stored in GCS bucket.

now my teammate asked me to downgrade as he has written some modules which are compatible with v0.12.28,i did downgrade my version but the remote state is still in v0.13.x.

now we are stuck with remote state having higher version.
what is the safest way to fix this?
we are in initial phase so we can destroy the whole infrastructure but still wanted to know a workaround for this.

Comment: Have you consider using `terraform refresh`? https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/refresh.html in theory it should update the state file and might roll back the version. Of course you should have no new features introduced in v0.13.x

Comment: @wisp terraform refresh was giving the same state mismatch error, anyway we ended up upgrading back to new version , destroying infrastructure and then downgrading the terraform and also removing the state file from GCS bucket, then we did terraform init.

Answer (score 2):

If you have versioning enabled in your backend bucket, I would suggest to

- **recover an older version of the state,**
- fix any diffs (e.g. import created resources since this version), and
- start working normally from thereon.

Unluckily this is a manual process and afaik there are no terraform commands supporting you in reverting the state to an earlier version.

#### additional notes

For the future my suggestion would be:

- Make sure versioning is enabled in your state-backend
- Make sure to pin your terraform version by specifying it as a constraint.

e.g. by creating a `versions.tf`:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.12.28"
}
```

You can also pin provider verisons in there (e.g. if you need to stick with aws provider 2.x for any reason)

```
terraform {
  required_version = "0.12.28"

  required_providers {
    aws = ">= 2.58, < 3.0"
  }
}
```